# DevExtreme component is not available in event parameter

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme, devextreme-angular

Most of the event methods provided by DevExtreme components pass in an event object which has the event-triggering component as a child. In the handling event method I can then just use the component from the event parameter and I don't have to reference the component with the @ViewChild mechanism. In most cases this just works perfectly. However - if I use DxForm to create my form components dynamicall and give the following object to DxForm's items parameter it won't work any more:

```
[{
   dataField: 'postingText',
   editorType: 'dxAutocomplete',
   editorOptions: {
       dataSource: this._listService.PostingTextDataSource,
       onValueChanged: (changedValue) => this.autocompleteChanged(changedValue) 
   }
}]
```

My event handling method autocompleteChanged will be called and I get the event object. The event object has also a component child. But this component object is somehow broken:

[image]

As you can see the component object has no useful properties. And most of the properties start with an underscore (are they some kind of private/protected?).

What do I wrong? Is it really not possible to get the component this easy?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Form editors don't provide a Form component in their event handlers. They provide only information about themselves (you can check the *element* parameter as well - it is an editor's element, not a Form's one).

So in your case, the component parameter is an Autocomplete's instance and you have to use the ViewChild decorator.

Alternatively, you can grab the Form's instance from the [onInitialized](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Angular_Components/Component_Configuration_Syntax/#Call_Methods) event handler.

They have code snippets in the [Angular Components - Call Methods](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Angular_Components/Component_Configuration_Syntax/#Call_Methods) topic.